# VBA: create new rows and auto-fill them with data from different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 2 sheets with the below information:

**SheetB**
Item1
Item2

**SheetC**
LocationA
LocationB
LocationC

And I am trying to have the below result in SheetA:

**SheetA**
Item1 LocationA
Item1 LocationB
Item1 LocationC
Item2 LocationA
Item2 LocationB
Item2 LocationC

I use this vba code to copy the Items from SheetB to SheetA, but each item can be stored in different locations, so I'd like to have listed in SheetA each item from SheetB, and all the possible locations what are listed in SheetC. The idea of SheetA is to have a summary with all the information.

```
Worksheets("SheetB").ListObjects("ArtikelDBTable").ListColumns("ARTIKEL").DataBodyRange.Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("SheetA").ListObjects("WerbemittelTable").ListColumns("ARTIKEL").DataBodyRange
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a simple copy and paste, because you're not simply copying and pasting. You are generating a new structure/set of results based upon the input of 2 worksheets.You need to iterate through each column in SheetB, when you 'get' the first value then iterate through each on SheetC (whilst updating SheetA). Repeat until the next value in SheetB is empty

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Dave. That's what I finally did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution what I found:

```
Sub Makro1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim i3 As Long
    Dim i4 As Long
    Dim LastRowSht2 As Long
    Dim LastRowSht3 As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Tabelle2")
    Set sht3 = wb.Sheets("Tabelle3")

    'Find the last row (in column A) with data.
    LastRowSht2 = sht2.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastRowSht3 = sht3.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ii = 2
    i4 = 2

    For i = 2 To LastRowSht2

        For i3 = 2 To LastRowSht3
            sht1.Range("A" & ii) = sht2.Range("A" & i).Value
            sht1.Range("B" & ii) = sht3.Range("A" & i4).Value
            ii = ii + 1
            i4 = i4 + 1
        Next i3
        i4 = 2
    Next i
 End Sub
```